# Ruby repetitive values regexp matching, but smarter then look ahead

Tags: regex, ruby

i have a string like:

```lisp
(:a 100 :b (300 400 500 "hello") :c "hello")
```

Ideally i need to match groups like this:

":a", "100"

":b", "300 400 500 \"hello\""

":c" "hello"

So as you see this is simple key value matching from free-from-lisp-like code.

I tried many regexp patterns like: `(:\w+)(.+)(?::\w+)` but this isn't very helpfull for me.

Full pattern description: https://rubular.com/r/khV8BWzJMtkbwv

Is regexp suitable for this kind of parsing or should i just write my simple parser/use ready one?

Comment: Are you trying to parse something like reverse polish notation? Regex is insufficient if so (read up on regular grammars vs context-free grammars); you'll need a proper parser. You can do it with regex if you limit the parentheses nesting depth, but you'll have to add a clause for each depth supported. Ragel might be a good starting point.

Comment: @ChrisHeald is correct. You probably should write a small parser, modify an existing one https://gist.github.com/fogus/1686917 or try to modify the string to a known format (e.g. JSON).

Comment: You have illustrated the problem of expressing a question in terms of an example. It leaves the reader with the task of trying to figure out the actual question. I made certain assumptions in my answer, but from your link I now see they were not correct. I can only guess what you have in mind.  At the very minimum you need to show the desired return value for the example string you gave at the link. If `str` holds that test string, `str.count '(' #=> 33; str.count ')' #=> 19`, meaning the parentheses are unbalanced, making it even more challenging to determine what is the desired return value.

Answer (score 1):

```
str = '(:a 100 :b (300 400 500 "hello") :c "hello")'
```

```
arr = str.scan(/(:\p{Ll}+)\s+([^(\s]+|\([^)]+\))/)
  #=> [[":a", "100"],
  #    [":b", "(300 400 500 \"hello\")"],
  #    [":c", "\"hello\")"]]
```

This is not quite what was wanted, as the parentheses are retained in `"(300 400 500 \"hello\")"`. This could be dealt with in a separate step.

```
arr.map { |a,b| [a, b.gsub(/\A\(|\)\z/, '')] }
  #=> [[":a", "100"],
  #    [":b", "300 400 500 \"hello\""],
  #    [":c", "\"hello\""]]
```

We could write the regular expression in *free-spacing mode* to make it self-documenting:

```
/
(           # begin capture group 1 
  :         # match ':'
  \p{Ll}+   # match 1+ lower case Unicode letters
)           # end capture group 1
\s+         # match 1+ whitespaces
(           # begin capture group 2
  [^(\s]+   # match 1+ chars other than '(' and whitespace
  |         # or
  \(        # match a left paren
  [^)]+     # match 1+ chars other then ')'
  \)        # match ')'
)           # end capture group 2
/x          # free-spacing regex definition mode
```

Comment: It doesn't really look like the desired output, though, does it?

Comment: @Eric, I don't see a problem. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯